# Can the sequence/order of the options in the Visual Studio 2010 right click menu change?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, menu, sequence, right-click

I tend to use certain options more than others at different times during my Visual Studio 2010 experience.  Is there a way to rearrange the order of the options in the right click menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Tools menu, click Customize, and then click the Commands tab. Choose a context menu and then customize it as you see fit.